# How to properly (quickly) iterate over Reminders using AppleScript/osascript?

Tags: applescript, osascript

What is the proper, efficient way to iterate over Reminders using AppleScript?  The script below works as expected, but takes 18 seconds to iterate over 180 Reminders when run from the command line using osascript!  (This same script takes only 2-3 seconds when run from within the ScriptEditor.)

```
# Find all Reminders whose name contains "Alumni"
set findMe to "Alumni"
set answer to "Maches: "

tell application "Reminders"
    set names to name of every reminder
end tell

repeat with name in names
    if name contains findMe then
        set answer to answer & " --- " & name
    end if
end repeat

return answer
```

I've run this script two ways from the command line: As a compiled script:  `osascript testReminders2.scrpt` and as a text file:  `./testReminders2.applescript` (where this file begins with `#! /usr/bin/osascript`.  Both versions take about the same amount of time.

Comment: RE: "when run from the command line" -- exactly how are you running it?

Comment: Using osascript.

Comment: I know `osascript` is the executable, however how exactly are you using it?

Comment: The code is in a file named testReminders.scpt.  I run `osascript testReminders2.scpt` from the terminal.  (For what it's worth:  I had also a similar problem in the past when I tried to set up a script as a service.)

Comment: Try running it as a _shell script_ using a plain text file with a `#!/usr/bin/osascript` _shebang_, in **Terminal** execute the following _compound command_, `touch testReminders2; open -e testReminders2; chmod +x testReminders2`, copy and paste the _code_ and save the `testReminders2` _file_ and run it e.g. `./testReminders2 ` from the _directory_ you created/saved it in. Is the timing any different?

Comment: Both versions take the same amount of time.  (Although, today that time is about 7 seconds instead of 18.)

Comment: You might try making an AppleScript app out of your script and running that directly, skipping the osascript context switch. But honestly, you're probably not going to get any significant improvements unless you switch to AppleScriptObjC using EventKit.

Comment: So, you think it is the overhead that is slow, not the loop itself?  (In other words, if the number of reminders doubles, you expect the time to stay pretty close to the 18 to 20 second figure rather than doubling to 36 seconds?)

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with the Reminders app, But sometimes when AppleScript gets data from an app it returns the data *by reference*, not as a block of data (the difference is whether the data is passed to and stored in the script itself, or whether the data is stored in the app and the script retrieves it as it needs it). By ref can be much more efficient in some cases, but in a loop like this it can sometimes bog things down.

Comment: Crossposted on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/417866/how-to-properly-quickly-iterate-over-reminders-using-applescript-osascript, got an answer there.